# Ways to provide read only views of subsets of DevOps work items

Tags: azure-devops, scrum, issue-tracking

I use Azure DevOps to track work items and bugs for a project. I'd like to grant certain people external to the project a read-only view of work items that are related to them (eg. tagged `Person X`), but without having to grant them access to DevOps. I have been toying with the idea of setting up a flow in Power Apps to continuously update a shared excel spreadsheet based on work items in DevOps, but I fear I might be missing easier/better options. How would you provide a limited read-only view of a backlog to externals?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to grant certain people external to the project a read-only
> view of work items that are related to them (eg. tagged Person X), but
> without having to grant them access to DevOps.

For this issue , I am afraid that this is unachievable in azure devops. At present, there is no such permission setting in azure devops to restrict external people can only read work items with specified tag.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: It is not clear to me whether or not this allows for only giving access to a subset of work items, which is part of what I want to achieve. I specifically don't want to make available the entire backlog, but filter on tags.

Comment: Do you mean that external people can only read work items with specified tag? If so, I am afraid that this is unachievable in azure devops .

Comment: That is what I mean, yes. Thank you for clarifying that this can not be done in DevOps. I  am now looking at more complicated solutions using a Flow to populate a spreadsheet. It seems to work for me, but it feels brittle.

Comment: Thanks for your response, according to the actual situation, I updated the answer. If it is helpful ,you could consider to accept it as an answer . In addition , if you have any progress about solution, welcome to share it here.